# Statistical difference per group

Tags: wald-test

I am calculating elasticities per income quintiles. I have 10,000 observations of elasticities calculated for each quintile, so a dataset of 5*10,000.

I would like to test whether the elasticities are stat. different per income-group.

How should I do this?

Can I calculate the mean over all samples and use the Wald-test to see if the mean for each individual quintile is statistically different from the overall mean?

Any other ideas?

Comment: Why specifically the quintiles? Why not the whole distribution? How many groups?

Comment: We are trying to test whether elasticity of demand varies by income-group. Simply judging from the plot, 10 is too many income groups, 3 is not enough, so we settled for 5. But what do you mean the whole distribution?

Comment: Why is this not just an ANOVA problem?